# How can I store data on elements and send it to another elemen in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to develop a coupon widget for a bet website.

I have links (odds) to be clicked. So this  element should carry match code, the odd etc...

When the user clicks,it should append all data to a div.

```
$('a').click(function(){
$('ul#fs').append('<li id="k401" class="first"><input id="chk401" type="checkbox"><label for="chk401"><strong> Jagellonia - Wisla Krakow</strong></label><a href="#"><i class="icon-remove icon-red"></i></a><span>Mbs:4</span><span class="mTip">FS</span><span class="odd">1: 2,20</span></li>');
  })
```

How can I do that? jQuery.data() is the best option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would store that data within an object on the data attribute and parse that to build your html.  Here is jsBin example to show you what i mean.

http://jsbin.com/enequr/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HTML5, I would go for HTML5 data attributes - it's easy and it's valid.

You can read their values with jQuery's `data()` method.

See this: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes

Comment: Thank you very much. http://www.orangesoda.net/jquery.dataset.html plugin helped me a lot.

Comment: Moreover, HTML5 data attributes are more easy to generate from your backend, e.g. PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes data() is the recommended way of associating data with jquery objects.

```
$('a').click(function(){
  var yourdata = $(this).data('yourproperty'); 
  // Do whatever you want with your data
})
```